# Usb Dongle To Erase Disk

Tags: security, usb, disk, erase, dongle

I need a solution for computer disk security.

User will use computer with a usb dongle, when this dongle is plugged everything is ok, but if usb unplugged, disk will be destroyed immediately.

There are two scenarios :

1- User will shut down computer (while dongle is plugged) , but before open it again, system will check if dongle is plugged or unplugged while booting the system, if unplugged, will destroy everything in disk before OS installed.

2- While user is working on computer , by the time unplug the dongle , system will detect it and will destroy disk immediately. Without waiting any command , only unplug the usb, and everything will be destroyed by the time.

Is there any way to do this ? 
I need a way for both scenarios . 
For Windows, Linux , and Mac also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easily way it is write your own USB driver for dongle, when your dongle have disconnected try to execute some code without a OS, if you make it you may format disk through your code, setup bios password and make MBR with your code, wich can not be replaced.

Comment: Ok, i will try to write my own driver. But i have a problem with this, "I don't know how can I do this". I wrote C and know a bit but not an expert. How can I wrote something like that ? Where must I start from ?